# Can’t establish a connection to the server websocket (Fargate, R shiny)

Tags: amazon-web-services, shiny, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I've spinned up the Rshiny the appication on ECS cluster using Fargate. The app works fine when accessed via registered target IP (from ALB). However, when the app is accessed through the ALB DNS name, Rshiny application greys out.

`Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://my-app-address:44977/websocket/`

I have tried to rebuild my app with:

```
timer <- reactiveTimer(1000 * 60 * 5) # time unit in milliseconds     
observe({
            timer()
            {{"here insert your code to submit a message through websocket client"}}        
})
```

but no effect.

Has anybody came across the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

as I remember, we need to enable Sticky Session on ALB/TargetGroup to make Socket works through ALB.

Comment: I did turn on stickiness on my target group, so far my app greys out as previously

Comment: ws://my-app-address:44977 I think the issue is the LB doesn't listen on port 44977, you need to change it is ALB https port. In my setup, we simply point to ALB DNS name without port.